# Drupal 8 clear cache causes the website to redirect to the install page

Tags: caching, drupal, installation

I'm running Drupal 8. Whenever I clear the cache, it causes the website to go down or go to the install page. How can I find out what's causing this to happen?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If it is meant to be a question you should not include your answer here, see [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You can, however, answer your own question by posting  your answer below. Please edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP error log.

Often it's a MySQL execution issue and you'll see this error:

```
General error 2006 MySQL server has gone away.
```

And can be due to the size of the blobs in MySQL exceeding the `max_allowed_packet` size set in the my.ini file.

The solution is to increase `max_allowed_packet`.